# Oxygen XML Debugger with initial template

Tags: debugging, oxygenxml

I am having problems running the Oxygen (v. 17.1) XSLT debugger without specifying an XML input document. The XSLT opens several files with the document() function and does not need to be applied to a specific XML document as input. Rather, I defined an initial template in the transformation configuration.

The transformation works as expected; however, in the debugger, I still have to choose an XML document from the XML-Dropdown menu. It doesn't seem to matter at all which document I choose (I can even choose the XSLT file itself), but as long as I don't select any document from the dropdown, the debugger controls remain greyed out and I cannot step into the first instruction.

Is this a bug or did I oversee some configuration option?

Thanks,
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to the XSLT debugger perspective with only the XSLT stylesheet opened. In the XML and XSL combo boxes you can choose the XSLT stylesheet.
There is a combo box in which you can use the XSLT processor (in your case it's probably Saxon 9 PE) and after that combo box there is a small XSLT processor configuration button which you can press to edit the used initial template.

Regards,
Radu

Comment: Right, I tried that before and it works, as does choosing any other XML file in the XML combo box. It is a bit unintuitive, however, to specify the XSLT file in the XML combo. Maybe worth adding a check-box or something...

Comment: I know, we'll try to improve on this in a future Oxygen version, we already have an issue registered for this.